# Faster way of reading csv to grid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, csv, datagridview

I have following in Windows Forms .NET 3.5

It works fine for csv with records less than 10,000 but is slower for records above 30,000.
Input csv  file can can any records between 1 - 1,00,000 records

Code currently used :

```
/// <summary>
        /// This will import file to the collection object
        /// </summary>
        private bool ImportFile()
        {
            try
            {

                String fName;
                String textLine = string.Empty;
                String[] splitLine;

                // clear the grid view

                accountsDataGridView.Rows.Clear();

                fName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fName))
                {
                    System.IO.StreamReader objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fName);

                    do
                    {
                        textLine = objReader.ReadLine();
                        if (textLine != "")
                        {
                            splitLine = textLine.Split(',');
                            if (splitLine[0] != "" || splitLine[1] != "")
                            {
                                accountsDataGridView.Rows.Add(splitLine);
                            }
                        }
                    } while (objReader.Peek() != -1);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.Contains("The process cannot access the file"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The file you are importing is open.", "Import Account", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

                return false;
            }

        }
```

Sample Input file :
 
18906,Y
18908,Y
18909,Y
18910,Y
18912,N
18913,N

Need some advice on optimizing this code for fast reads & view in grid.

Comment: What means  _slow_ for you, one second or one hour? Is it really too slow or just premature optimization?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Application hangs(for 3seconds) if records are more than 30k. This is slow & should be avoided. But thats not the case if records lower than 30k

Comment: If it _hangs_ the issue is probably not that it needs 3 seconds but that it "freezes". Use a background worker then.

Comment: @TimSchmelter rather than using a background worker, my question is whether it can be done in more faster way?

Comment: Imho there's nothing obvious that you can improve. However, this might be more appropriate on [**Codereview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if it works but you think that it can be improved.

Comment: Oops I thought SO would be ideal for this, I was not aware there would be one more forum for this! Anyways I have posted it there as well : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20145/faster-way-of-reading-csv-to-grid

Comment: In improving performance you should first always measure exactly where code spends its time. If its in visualizing the loaded data you can optimize this by only showing the first results (10) or so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<string[]> rows = File.ReadAllLines("Path").Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("1");
dt.Columns.Add("2");
rows.ForEach(x => {
  dt.Rows.Add(x);
});
dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

Try that, I suspected that you have some form of column names in the datagrid for now I just made them 1 and 2.

To filter as per your original code use:

```
List<string[]> rows = File.ReadAllines("Path").Select(x => x.Split(',')).Where(x => x[0] != "" && x[1] != "").ToList();
```

To get your columns from the `DataGridView`

```
  dt.Columns.AddRange(dgv.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Select(x => new DataColumn(x.Name)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Column names are already defined.(not shown in code although)

Comment: @Pratik I have changed the code to encoporate getting your column names from the datagrid should that be what you need, let me know what the performance is like and I can point you to something else to speed it up.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting the data directly into the grid you should take a look at the [`VirtualMode` of the `DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode.aspx).

In your code you're doing two things at one time (read the file, fill the grid), which leads to your freezed gui. Instead you should put the grid into the virtual mode and read the file within a `BackgroundWorker` into a list which holds the data for the grid. The background worker can after each line read update the virtual size of the grid, which allows to already see the data while the grid is loading. By using this approach you'll getting a smooth working grid.

Below you'll find an example which just needs to be filled into a form that uses a `DataGridView` with two text columns, a `BackgroundWorker` and a `Button`:

```
public partial class FormDemo : Form
{
    private List<Element> _Elements;

    public FormDemo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _Elements = new List<Element>();

        dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dataGridView.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView.VirtualMode = true;
        dataGridView.CellValueNeeded += OnDataGridViewCellValueNeeded;

        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += OnBackgroundWorkerDoWork;
        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += OnBackgroundWorkerProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnBackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    private void OnBackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var filename = (string)e.Argument;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            string line = null;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var parts = line.Split(',');

                if (parts.Length >= 2)
                {
                    var element = new Element() { Number = parts[0], Available = parts[1] };
                    _Elements.Add(element);
                }

                if (_Elements.Count % 100 == 0)
                {
                    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnBackgroundWorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView.RowCount = _Elements.Count;
    }

    private void OnBackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView.RowCount = _Elements.Count;
        button.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnButtonLoadClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker.IsBusy
            && DialogResult.OK == openFileDialog.ShowDialog())
        {
            button.Enabled = false;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(openFileDialog.FileName);
        }
    }

    private void OnDataGridViewCellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = _Elements[e.RowIndex];

        switch (e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                e.Value = element.Number;
                break;

            case 1:
                e.Value = element.Available;
                break;
        }
    }

    private class Element
    {
        public string Available { get; set; }

        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much to optimize in regards to speed, but following is much more readable. If it is too slow, it probably isn't the method *reading* the file, but your WinForm that needs to display >30k records.

```
    accountsDataGridView.Rows.Clear();
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var fields = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
            if (fields.Length == 2 && (fields[0] != "" || fields[1] != ""))
            {
                accountsDataGridView.Rows.Add(fields);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [SuspendLayout()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) and [ResumeLayout()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout.aspx) Methods.

[From MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx)
"The SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout methods are used in tandem to suppress multiple Layout events while you adjust multiple attributes of the control. For example, you would typically call the SuspendLayout method, then set the Size, Location, Anchor, or Dock properties of the control, and then call the ResumeLayout method to enable the changes to take effect."

```
accountsDataGridView.SuspendLayout();
accountsDataGridView.Rows.Clear();

// .....
// in the end after you finished populating your grid call

accountsDataGridView.ResumeLayout();
```