# import a CSV file into datagridview C#?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, datagridview

I have been digging from last 4 hours to find a **simplest solution** to import a csv file into datagridview in C# and i am unable to find the appropriate solution.

then hopelessly, I decided to ask user to convert csv to excel first and then import but its too unromantic.
here is the code for importing excel:

```
        string pathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + txtPath.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(pathConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter ODA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select *from [" + txtSheet.Text + "$]", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ODA.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

**Question:**
To import CSV, what should be the connectionString using this code.? Or there is no simple soultion?

Comment: see this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157153/faster-way-of-reading-csv-to-grid) in stackoverflow

Comment: Side note: beware of sql injection - you should never build your query by *concatenating text values from users*. Instead use parameterized queries as seen in these examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12048152/3773066) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9401888/3773066).

Comment: the connection string is different for text files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813607/parsing-csv-using-oledb-using-c-sharp, https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/

Answer (score 1):

I have this snippet from my old project, hope this helps:

```
string csvFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "aCSVfile.csv");
List<string[]> rows = File.ReadAllLines(csvFile).Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

//add cols to datatable:
dataTable.Columns.Add("col0");
dataTable.Columns.Add("col1");

rows.ForEach(x => { dataTable.Rows.Add(x); });

dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```