# C# Inserting last 5 lines from a .csv file into datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am trying to pull that last 5 lines from a .csv file and display them in a datagrid on my form. How would I insert the data onto the datagrid?

Here is my current Code,

```
        int x = 5;   
        var buffor = new Queue<string>(x);

        var log = new StreamReader(@"MyPath");

        while (!log.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = log.ReadLine();

            if (buffor.Count >= x)
                buffor.Dequeue();
            buffor.Enqueue(line);
        }

        string[] lastLines = buffor.ToArray();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int x = 5;
            var buffor = new Queue<string>(x);
            foreach (var headerLine in File.ReadLines("C:/NewMap.csv").Take(1))
            {
                foreach (var headerItem in headerLine.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(headerItem.ToString().Trim(), headerItem.ToString());
                }
            }
            var log = new StreamReader("C:/NewMap.csv");

            while (!log.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = log.ReadLine();

                if (buffor.Count >= x)
                    buffor.Dequeue();
                buffor.Enqueue(line);
            }

            foreach (var line in buffor)
            {
                if (line != string.Empty || line != string.Empty)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the same amount of columns? My csv file  has eight columns of info, when inserted to datagrid it combines into one

Comment: Yes you can have, just define it in the datagrid, mark as answer if it has helped

Comment: how would I define it in the datagrid, I am very new to datagrids, sorry

Comment: It will be something like this   dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column1", "Age");

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157153/faster-way-of-reading-csv-to-grid

Comment: would I just use the split on line?

Comment: @Shadow89 you can defined the columns initially and then it is a matter of assigning the datagrid source

Comment: I already had the columns defined, but it just pushed them over

Comment: can you give me teamviewer?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know what that is

Comment: I used your code above and put in my paths, and it finds the info and puts it into one column, I just need to know with the code you supplied above, how do I spit the information into my predefined columns?